# WebBrowser control not navigating to links to "file://" protocol URIs

Tags: .net, winforms, webbrowser-control, file-uri

I am setting the `DocumentText` property to an HTML string that contains links like:

```
<a href="file:///D:/dir/file.html">NewPage</a>
```

The links are shown properly in the WebBrowser, but nothing happens when I click them. The Navigating, Navigated and `DocumentComplete` events do not fire - nothing seems to happen at all.

`AllowNavigation` is true and other links using HTTP are working.

Any ideas please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DocumentText was causing too many problems, so I implemented a tiny HTTP server which makes the WebBrowser control happy:

http://www.nickbutler.net/Article/WebBrowserEx

Nick